Kotlin lombok builder annotation doesn't work
Lombok kotlin annotation doesn't work at all
here are my plugins inside the build.gradle file (groovy):
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "2.0.0"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.lombok' version '2.0.0'
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "5.3.0"
}

I didn't add any lombok dependencies, only plugins
here is my data class:
@Builder
data class UserDTO(/...fields/)
Im trying to do this: UserDTO.builder()....build()
but it even doesn't have a builder property

why use Lombok with Kotlin, instead of optional constructor parameters?

@sidgate I was forced to use it once, imo only reason to do that is if you have to interop with (legacy) java codebase. It doesn't bring any value to kotlin code itself.

@sidgate it is actually a lot of boilerplate code when you add to each param "? = null"
